# alternate row colors using jquery

Tags: jquery, row

Using jQuery and not CSS, is it possible to alternate row colors between records? If so can anyone provide a short code script on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I fully believe that CSS is the way to go for this. Zebra striping is cosmetic anyhow, so your application will work even in old browsers that don't support those CSS selectors. Doing this with JavaScript is overkill and could lead to inconsistent styling if you ever add or remove DOM nodes. I'd be curious to know why CSS is ruled out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

Answer (score 9):

Do you just not want to use CSS for cross-browser (i.e., IE) support?  If so, you *could* keep the styling in the CSS and just use jQuery to set the class.

For example:

```
<style>
    /* tr:nth-child(even) */
    tr.even { background-color: white; }
    /* tr:nth-child(odd) */
    tr.odd { background-color: black; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){
        // Apply to each table individually and make sure nothing is doubleclassed
        // if you run this multiples of times.
        $('table').each(function() {
            $('tr:odd',  this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
            $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can select `tr` elements from a table and css accepts a function as a parameter, which will return a value based on some criteria you decide.  In this case, you can test the index for evenness.

```
$("#table tr").css("background-color", function(index) {
    return index%2==0?"blue":"red";
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Zny/

Comment: I thought this answer might be faster than the accepted answer since it doesn't have to select the rows twice, but my test shows that the accepted answer is actually fastest to my surprise: http://jsperf.com/jquery-even-odd-vs-css-callback

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses the Sizzle Seletor Engine, which is cool because it uses the same syntax as CSS. So you use the same selector as CSS but then use the jQuery `.css()` function to alter the elemen't CSS:

```
$('#table_id').find('tr:even').css({'background-color':'red'})
              .end().find('tr:odd').css({'background-color':'blue'});
```

This code example selects the table you want to alter, then selects all the even child elements (`tr`'s) and changes their background color, it then uses `.end()` to return to the previous selection of the entire table and selects the odd rows to alter their CSS.

Comment: You can't use `children` because browsers typically insert a tbody around free table rows.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, I can't say I ever use tables. Thanks.

Comment: `$('#table_id').find('>tr:even,>tbody>tr:even')`... should make the trick in case tbody is unknown

Comment: @CharlesHETIER I'm not sure I follow. If you omit the `>` (child) part of the selector, then the existence of `tbody` doesn't really matter. Also, if you omit `tbody` from your HTML, it's one of the things that browsers will auto-fix for you (like omitting ending `</li>` tags).

Comment: Jasper, you are perfectly right regarding the fact that the browser systematically generates the missing tbody, I didn't noticed that. The main focus of this snippet was to propose a alternative to children based on`>` selector to limit search scope, thus avoid tfoot, thead,nested tables to be impacted and save some performances:
`$('#table_id').find('>tbody>tr:even')` is enougth

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to change color of alternate row. I have taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/set-alternate-row-colors-in-jQuery.php

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       window.jQuery("tr:odd" ).css("background-color","#fbcff5" );
       window.jQuery("tr:even").css("background-color","#bbbbff");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to skip over hidden rows (or another attribute, say `class="struck"`):

```
<style>
tr.struck{background-color:#633;color:white;}
tr.eee{background-color:#EEE;color:#000;}
tr.fff{background-color:#FFF;color:#000;}
</style>
function doZebra(){
     var tTrCnt=0;
     $("##tblData tbody tr").each(function(){
         if($(this).css("display")!="none" && !$(this).hasClass("struck")){
             tTrCnt++;
             if(tTrCnt % 2) $(this).removeClass().addClass("eee");
             else  $(this).removeClass().addClass("fff");
         }
     });
}
```