# Alternate black and white colors for a chess board using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create alternate black and white colors for chess board using jQuery with `div` elements only (no nested one's) and also without using [id's or class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128581/alternate-row-colors-using-jquery)?

I created a sample example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/W7p5F/19/)

Comment: i know css, but i am new to jQuery. Just curious about selectors in jQuery. :)

Comment: can i provide the jquery code for your question?

Comment: which <div>s do you want to color? is it all <div>s or a specific <div>?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No changes to your HTML required.

```
$('#mainChessBoard div').each(function(index){
    $(this).css('background-color', (parseInt(index / 8) + index) % 2 == 0 ? 'grey' : '#CCCCCC');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7p5F/24/

Comment: yes, great. its all about logical thinking. thank you very much.

Comment: So, how would you do this if you have uneven number of rows?

Comment: @Syedur, what do you mean? There's no code change needed. Go ahead and edit the fiddle and add another row.

Comment: @aquinas, I meant if you're working with uneven number of cells with in a board. A chess board will always be 8x8. However, what if you're working with a 9x9 board (like Go)? Dividing by 8 or n will only work when n is an even number in this equation.

Comment: Ah. Well, any odd number configuration is simple: `index % 2 == 0 ? 'grey' : '#CCCCCC'`,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with jQuery, add a blank (width: 0) div after each H column to inverse the parity of the new row.

---

UPDATE: I meant something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W7p5F/23/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to change your HTML and CSS a bit but I'm guessing this is what you wanted. It's done with :odd and :even selectors in jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/U8kZe/

I've wrapped your rows of 8 squares in another div to acheive this.

Comment: He knows about the odd and even selectors, see his example... and he wants it without nesting.

Comment: Ah yeah. Oh well. Killed a bit of time waiting for some advice on a Drupal issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your current JSfiddle example is fine (using :odd and :even selectors). However, I'd actually recommend using a table (instead of DIVs) for this particular UI. Then you can easily combine row selectors with TD (table data cell) selectors to alternate colors.